# Firefox add-on to add a .css and a .js file to a page

Tags: javascript, css, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, add-on

I want to make a **Firefox add-on** that adds a custom **CSS** and **JavaScript** file to the pages on http://*.example.com. Doing it with **Chrome Extensions** is pretty simple, but Firefox add-ons are a little bit confusing. What is the **most simple way** to do that? How can I make that add-on, **step by step**?

Comment: For the css part: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373678/inject-a-css-file-into-a-webpage-via-firefox-extension

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the page-mod api, here is the documentation ( including simple code examples ):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod

In particular, you add js files using the `contentScriptFile` option, and css files using the `contentStyleFile` option. Here's a very simple example:

```
var data = require('sdk/self').data;

require('sdk/page-mod').PageMod({
  include: ["*"],
  contentScriptFile: [data.url('script.js')],
  contentScriptFile: [data.url('style.css')],
  attachTo: ["existing", "top"]
});
```

This code should be in `./lib/main.js` in your add-on project directory and the files `script.js` and `style.css` should be located in the `./data/` sub-folder of your add-on project directory.